# Isolate PHP applications with Docker

Tags: php, docker, webserver, devops

I am trying to setup set of docker containers to serve couple of applications.
One of my goals is to isolate PHP applications from eachother.

I am new to Docker and not fully understand its concepts.
So only idea i came up with is to create a dedicated php-fpm container per-application.

I started with official `image: php:7.0-fpm` but now I think that I may need to create my own general purpose pfp-fpm container (based on mentioned above), add some programs to it (such as ImageMagick) and instantiate couple of such php-fpm+stuff containers per PHP-application, setting up volume pointing strictly to that application source code.

Am I thinking in right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> now I think that I may need to create my own general purpose pfp-fpm container (based on mentioned above), add some programs to it

That is the idea: you can make a Dockerfile starting with `FROM php:7.0-fpm`, with your common programs installed in it.

Then you can make a multiple other Dockerfiles (each in their different folder), starting with `FROM <yourFirstImage>`, and declaring specifics to each php applications.

Comment: In this case - requirements for all the apps are similar, this is not the point (but I got what you are saying, thank you!). Main question was - Do I really need to keep a container with FPM per-application I want to isolate?

Comment: And if it is so - how resource consuming is that? How can I measure how much ram or CPU I will spend on each PHP-FPM container instance?

Comment: @SmxCde "Do I really need to keep a container with FPM-per application I want to isolate?": yes, if you want to avoid any side-effect between each apps, as each one will run in its own machine (ows disk space and memory)

Comment: @SmxCde "how resource consuming is that?": it depends on their activity: as long as those apps are not doing much, it won't consume much if any CPU or even disk space, due to the copy-on-write mechanism.